# Is it possible to segue between nibs?

Tags: ios, swift, nib

I know you can segue between nib and storyboard and programmatically segue, but is it possible to segue between two nibs.?

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDeets", sender: tableView)
```

Comment: you should provide more context. I can just suppose that you have some custom views inside a controller and you want the transition like between view controllers. That is possible if you use a container view controller and depending on the presentation mode you need, you can opt for using a uinav controller inside that container view or some other view controller management system.

Comment: It is not possible to pass Segue between nibs. Instead You can pass storyboard id with UIViewController class name.